# Cross-browser CSS when adjusting a WordPress theme

Tags: css

[image]

[image]

My CSS:

```
.n-drop-cap::first-letter {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--color-1);
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0.8rem;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  margin-bottom: -2rem;
  display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="n-drop-cap">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
```

This is **a case of adjusting a ready made WordPress theme** for my needs. So, I have not reset the CSS styles. I decided that maybe it is not necessary in this case.

Anyway, my styles has not proved to be cross browser. In Chrome it looks satisfactorily (uppermost screen shot). **In Firefox it falls apart.**

Web page: https://galina.xyz/krasota/strizhki-na-korotkie-volosy/

How can I make everything cross-browser?

Comment: `display: block` is not supported for `:first-letter` selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Comment: Thank you. That was really the problem. If you organize it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `:first-letter` does not supports `display` property.

All supported CSS rules subset can be found in it's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

You can always wrap your first letter manually or via script and then apply style for it:

```css
.first-letter {
  padding: 0 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #D93588;
}
```

```html
<span class="first-letter">3</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eu lectus ac tortor commodo molestie at sit amet nunc. Vestibulum quis risus maximus, elementum urna nec, egestas lorem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Quisque porta accumsan sem, a lobortis tortor faucibus finibus. Maecenas ac risus sed ante dictum sagittis. Nullam magna mi, consequat vitae sodales ac, dapibus et velit. Etiam vel lectus sed metus aliquet aliquet. Etiam mattis risus quis urna scelerisque tempor. Aenean maximus, diam vitae efficitur vulputate, mauris sem cursus velit, sed aliquet diam elit ac leo. Curabitur ut volutpat justo. Fusce maximus semper mi ac feugiat. Aliquam laoreet enim purus, vitae tempor elit viverra consequat. Nunc mollis sodales enim sed dictum.
```